# Power to usb devices flickers briefly

Tags: windows-10, usb

About once every few minutes the power momentarily gets cut to one of my connected USB devices. It causes my keyboard input to hang briefly and my mouse input to break entirely until I remove and reconnect it. I can see it happen as the backlighting on my keyboard or mouse will briefly flicker off.
What I know about this issue is:

- it happens any time my computer is up and running
- as long as more than one usb device is connected it will never not happen but can be less frequent depending on what I have connected. Until recently I was using a specific mouse and keyboard that kept the problem pretty infrequent but theyre both dated now and the new ones i own cause the issue to happen much more often
- it only affects one out of any number of connected usb devices at a time
- the only thing that changes which device it affects is if I unplug some and reconnect them in different usb outlets
- it happens on every usb port on my device, the 3.0 and 3.1 ports built directly into my motherboard (Gigabyte x99 designare ex) and the 3.0 and 2.0 ports on the case
- it isn't a problem with a specific usb port I can connect devices to any set of the usb ports on my computer and one of them will exhibit the problem
- it sometimes takes an extra minute or so from when i first reboot my computer to when the problem starts
- if I have devices connected to the same set of ports the same specific port will have the problem every time. I have not yet experimented to see which port is affected by every combination of connected usb devices i can give it but the issue is consistent on that level
- the problem is only present when windows is active I have left my keyboard and mouse connected while sitting on my BIOS screen for a good 20 minutes and seen no flickering

What I have tried unsuccessfully to fix this so far:

- connecting multiple different wired keyboards and mice to the computer: the issue is present regardless so i doubt it's a problem with any of my specific usb devices
- uninstalling, reinstalling, and rolling back every driver related to every usb device and usb root hub and input: this has done nothing so far
- testing my devices on other computers: no problems here again i don't think it's a hardware issue
- checking my wiring connections for the case usb ports
- disabling windows' usb selective suspend feature
- disabling windows' ability to turn off devices and usb ports for power saving specifically in each driver properties window and overall in power plan settings

My computer for reference:

- Windows 10 pro, I've kept windows up to date since long before the issue cropped up which was around the end of summer 2017
- Motherboard: Gigabyte X99 Designare EX
- CPU: Intel i7 6850k
- Ram: 32gb

the old keyboard and mouse i used that only flickered once every couple of hours were a 2014 razer blackwidow and an old logitech mouse, the newer devices i've replaced them with have made the issue much worse but at the same time they have no problems working on any other computer so i don't think they're at fault for the problem

Comment: Are the case USB ports all connected to the same motherboard header (the issue could be common to the root hub)?  Have you ruled out the PSU (any evidence of any other kind of device experiencing power winking)? How about the motherboard power connections from the PSU?  Is the computer on a UPS?  Have you checked the driver for the USB root hub/ports?

Comment: I've reinstalled all the root hub drivers multiple times and nothing but usb devices has the problem, if it was an issue with the power supply not giving enough juice to the USB ports windows has an error message for that which I've never gotten and it would likely affect every USB device not just one. I do not have a ups I could look into that but it definitely seems like some sort of windows 10 specific problem

Comment: Try loading a live session of a Linux distro (if you don't have Linux familiarity, Mint with the Mate desktop would be pretty Windows-like, and a live session won't affect anything on your system).  See if you get the same problem.  If so, that identifies it as a hardware problem.  If not, it's an OS-specific issue like a driver problem.

Comment: i've already attempted something similar based on a guide i found which was to boot into the bios options and see if the problem persists there and nothing happened but i can try it with a live usb just in case

Comment: Have you used a power monitoring software, or etc to check the 5v channel of your power supply.  It is supposed to be +/- 5%, if it is outside of that range your power supply may not have enough amps on the 5v channel.  I would also use a self powered hub to test this theory.

Comment: do you have any examples of software i can use to check this?

Comment: @DroolSpout  Possibly speedfan, but I can't guarantee its compatibility.  However, it won't harm your system.  https://www.gigabyte.com/microsite/369/images/system-tweaking.html  System Information viewer, and then the **Record** tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue with my tower housing a Gigabyte B250m-DS3H motherboard and GeForce RTX 4000 graphics card. My new USB microphone refused to stay connected and my new wired keyboard would sporadically work/not work. A powered USB hub fixed the problem, so I believe it was a power supply issue. Thinking the addition of 'lighted' accessories (mousepad, keyboard, mouse, etc) have contributed to the power draw and issue.